# Creating "Text Cloud" like in comics

Tags: compositing-nodes, visibility

I need to create the "Text Cloud" like in comics. There should be "layers". The top layer is "Text" - the object inside the "Text Cloud". It should be higher than the cloud, i.e. at the highest level and be visible all the time. The second layer is the "Text Cloud" itself. It should be higher than the other objects in the scene, but lower than the "Text". Other objects in the scene are the third layer, they should be below the "Text Cloud" and the "Text" itself. I suspect that a composition needs to be applied here.

[image]

[image] (Blender v 3.3.0)

Comment: Are you sure you want the speech bubbles to be 3D? Always-on-top visibility combined with shading can look weird.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady How do you achieve always-on-top visibility? -- With an emission shader you can get rid of the shading if you don't like it. [This speech bubble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKPPM.jpg) has flipped faces, backface culling + emission. But it gets hidden other objects in the front.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady If this is not possible in the 3D version, then let it be 2D, if the condition of three layers is observed. But I will be surprised the 3D option is not possible in Blender

Comment: @Blunder one idea is to take advantage of Alpha Blend problem: https://i.imgur.com/LQzSi87.gif - you could do this dynamically by moving an object towards the camera with a driver or a constraint, and then moving the geometry within the same amount using geonodes. Or as OP says, just separate renders, composited in the order you wish. Or, what I'd go for, animating the speech bubbles to rotate as camera rotates, to simply stay closer to the camera. You probably want to align the text and camera orientation anyway for good readability (or maybe not, or maybe partially...)

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Yes, I saw how a similar problem was solved with the help of a composition. But in the example there were two layers, and I have three layers, and I don't know how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This version does the work in-scene, in front of the camera. The speech bubble is constructed in the XY plane, origin at its point, its components gathered into a collection.

Here, the bubble is set up as a GN modification of the speaking object. Just 3 simple clusters:

[image]

.. which adjusts the location of the bubble in the speaker's space, and lets you change its apparent size...

[image]

... which rotates the bubble to face the camera, (construction Y up speaker Z)

[image]

... which scales the bubble towards and away from the camera, allowing you to bring it in front of other scene objects, without changing its apparent size.

so.....

[image]

It works fine with a 3D bubble, too, (included in .blend) but there are less obvious decisions to be made about outlining, lighting, etc. Maybe come back with complaints, on that one.

[image]
.

Comment: Not what i expected, but works even better. Thank you. I suspect you are from the Blender development team.

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind when I wrote "or maybe partially" - very nice effect where the bubble is not static, but is readable at all times!

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady + arachnoden I'm glad it met the specs :)  Did something like this a while back for captioning a map, with constraints and drivers, as suggested. But it's _so_much easier to construct and use, in GN.  :D