# Is there a way to make object always face the active camera or just viewport with geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, camera, constraints, geometry, vector

Is there a way to make an object always rotate towards 3D view or active camera using geometry nodes without manually choosing targets, so it would work with multiple cameras in you scene?

I saw the tutorial on YT that someone made this work in shader editor using  vector displacement method. The problem is we work in EEVEE and this is not an option now.

I wonder, if this is possible with displacement mat, there should be a way to mimic this with actual geometry nodes right?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender.SE! Does this answer your question? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/267801/

Comment: See also [Creating "Text Cloud" like in comics](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/276360/60486)

Comment: Also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/243305/geometry-nodes-billboards-similar-to-track-to-constraint

Comment: Do you want to align the objects to a specific camera or do you use multiple cameras and the objects should always be aligned to the active camera?